# Testing TLS edge cases (renegotiation)

Tags: ssl

I'm writing protocol that encrypts whatever is being sent using TLS. For TLS, I'm using schannel on Windows.

For testing, I'm connecting to IIS, doing GET, and connecting using Chrome to my server, just sending back HTTP 200 response.

However, there are few edge cases I'm unable to check with this. I want to use someone else's implementation for reference, so I don't end up with bogus implementation on both sides.

Is there any testing TLS server (client), which can I use for testing

- renegotiation
- partially sent message
- extra data in handshake / message (`DecryptMessage` to have filled `SECBUFFER_EXTRA` buffer)

?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the newest TLS version (1.3) forbids renegotiation. See section 4.1.2 of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446

Comment: You have some skeleton here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server  that you can tweak and evolve to use as a testing case. On the client side you could use `openssl s_client`.